# Undergraduate Level Math Books

Tags: books, big-list

What are some good undergraduate level books, particularly good introductions to (Real and Complex) Analysis, Linear Algebra, Algebra or Differential/Integral Equations (but books in any undergraduate level topic would also be much appreciated)?

EDIT: More topics (Affine, Euclidian, Hyperbolic, Descriptive & Diferential Geometry, Probability and Statistics, Numerical Mathematics, Distributions and Partial Equations, Topology, Algebraic Topology, Mathematical Logic etc)

**Please post only one book per answer** so that people can easily vote the books up/down and we get a nice sorted list. If possible post a link to the book itself (if it is freely available online) or to its amazon or google books page.

Comment: This is borderline, but I think it is a legitimate question of interest to math instructors. I think its better as a community wiki though. 

Comment: It's no longer possible to add useful answers to this question (as there are too many!) and it's unclear whether this question would be "allowed" by modern standards -- far too broad. As it's been popping back to the front page fairly frequently, we've decided to close it.

Comment: See discussion on meta: http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/499/undergraduate-level-math-books-proposal-to-close/ (and remember to vote this comment up, so it is visible to others)

Comment: I don't have enough rep to rate anything and I only skimmed through the meta discussion but essentially what the mods did is bad for the website...

Most websites start with one thing and then change their purpose by the will of the users... Otherwise they fail miserably as soon as some competition shows up...

So the final judgment for closure "The system was created for people looking for precise answers to precise questions. Big list questions were an emergent phenomenon" is generally a flawed mindset.

Comment: I asked the question because I am an undergraduate student and want to learn more about math... A lot of great books were recommended here and I guess what was suggested so far is more then enough for me to read... So at this point I don't really care about the policies at MathOverflow but my friendly advice is given in the preceding comment...

And NO I'm not gonna create a new account for meta just for one post  ¬_¬ 

Comment: ..also I suggest a "Hide Question" option for users who are tired of seeing a question pop on the home page

Comment: Ordinary Differential Equations by Garrett Birkhoff and Gian-Carlo Rota. 

Answer (score 28):

Algebraic Topology by Hatcher (available online [here](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATpage.html)).

Comment: If you like print books (easier to carry around, scribble in, etc.), Hatcher's book sells for $37, which seems pretty reasonable.

Answer (score 26):

*Generatingfunctionology* by Wilf is fun, [free](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html), requires very little in the way of prerequisites, and is as good an introduction to the methods of analytic combinatorics as could be asked for. It's long been one of my favorite textbooks.

Comment: The free edition is the second (early 1990s?); there's a third edition (2005), which as of now is not free.  The third edition doesn't differ that much from the second one, though.

For a more advanced book that massively expands upon Wilf, I recommend Flajolet and Sedgewick's <i>Analytic Combinatorics</i>, published 2009 (also available <a href="http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/AnaCombi/index.html">free online!</a>) -- but this is really a graduate-level text.

Answer (score 24):

Spivak, *Calculus*

Comment: I agree, with the caveat that the subject of the book is usually called "Elementary Real Analysis" these days.

That said, when I first read this book I loved it so much that it made me want to be a mathematician.  It's both rigorous AND intuitive, in a way that both qualities complement one another.

Answer (score 24):

Concrete Mathematics, Graham, Knuth and Patashnik. Extremely useful, very good exercises, and a sense of humor that appeals to me.

Comment: I finally gave in and bought this book last week, after realizing that at any given moment over the last few years I was more likely to have it checked out of the library than not.

Answer (score 23):

A basic undergrad algebra book which I feel is not as well known as it should be is Michael Artin's [Algebra](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0130047635). I have it in soft cover so I hope it's actually the one in this Amazon link. Anyway it's beautifully written, provides context and motivation and is just a pleasure to read or browse. How often do you find a basic text written by a world-class expert?

"Always study from the masters".

Comment: As far as I know there is only one book by Michael Artin with that title.  I have the hardcover and it looks like the one you link to.  Apparently Artin is working on a new edition.

Comment: That book is so much better than Dummit and Foote for undergraduates.  D&F is also useless at the graduate level, where much better texts like Lang blow it out of the water.  

Comment: Artin is going to be rough going for undergraduates who are not well versed in basic geometry and linear algebra,fpqc.But you can't help but love the infectious passion with which Artin weaves his craft in front of the students.He loves algebra and he's trying to prosyletize his students to it. A book with a similar geometric bent,level and also by a master that students will probably find easier going is E.B.Vinberg's A COURSE IN ALGEBRA. But Artin's book is very good and it's good news for all of us that Artin is revising it.

Answer (score 22):

For undergraduate level topology (mostly point set topology) I recommend "Topology" by Munkres. I learned topology from this book as an undergrad and I remember this being one of my favorite books at the time.

Comment: I felt the same, it is great to read as an undergrad (I recommend students to try to do most of the proofs mentally instead of reading them).

Answer (score 20):

Milnor, Topology from the differentiable viewpoint.

Comment: A variant that many prefer over Milnor would be Guillemin and Pollack's Differential Topology. 

Comment: @Ryan. It's a matter of taste, of course. Milnor does much less material that Guillemin and Pollack, but reading it was an amazing experience for me. Guillemin and Pollack is a very good book, but I never got nearly as much from it. 

Comment: No no no!! This book is **awful** as an undergraduate text! It's a great reference for someone who already knows the material, but the proofs skip many "simple" steps, and the author makes no attempt to explain the concepts from a intuitive point of view! Our professor assigned this book for the undergraduate course in Topology at SUNY Stony Brook, and at the time it was of absolutely no help to me whatsoever.

Answer (score 18):

Serre, A Course in Arithmetic.

Answer (score 16):

The [Chicago undergraduate mathematics bibliography](http://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~abhishek/chicmath.htm) is a nice annotated list of books.

Comment:  Our own Pete Clark is one of the authors of that list way back when he was an undergraduate there,I believe,Michael.

Comment: Pete's online CV has him graduating from Chicago in '98, so you're right (unless two mathematicians named Pete Clark came from Chicago in the same year!)

Comment: +1000 It was a GREAT idea to develop a database of critical reviews sorted by subject and difficulty level, a few of them by multiple people. Even if the list itself is somewhat obsolete, one gets a good feel of relative strengths and weaknesses of "canonical texts" ca 1998.

Answer (score 16):

Ordinary Differential Equations by Vladimir I. Arnold

Answer (score 16):

Needham, *Visual Complex Analysis*. I read this while in high school, and it's simply beautiful. I recommend this book as a *supplement* to any first course in complex analysis (a different book should probably be used for the main textbook since Needham's is very pretty, very engaging, but not very rigorous).

Comment: Excellent book.  


Answer (score 16):

Miles Reid, Undergraduate Algebraic Geometry.

ps - anyone who thinks one can teach an undergraduate class out of Hatcher's Algebraic Topology (which is a great book) at more than 10 universities in the US is sadly deluded.  Ditto for a few more things I've seen here.

pps - somewhere between a third and half of the math majors here could handle abstract algebra out of Artin.  It would be great for those that could, but we're not going to ditch half our students.

Comment: Very astute comments! Many answers to "best textbook" questions are way off the deep (macho) end.

Answer (score 15):

Not exactly one of the topics in the question, but I particularly liked Silverman and Tate's *Rational Points on Elliptic Curves*.

Answer (score 14):

Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces, by Manfredo Do Carmo 
is an excellent introductory book.

[https://www.amazon.com/Differential-Geometry-Curves-Surfaces-Manfredo/dp/0132125897](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132125897)

Answer (score 12):

The [Princeton Lectures in Analysis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/069111384X) by Stein and Shakarchi are great introductions to Fourier, complex, and real analysis (in that order!).

Answer (score 12):

Complex Analysis, by Lars Ahlfors

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lars_Ahlfors

Comment: It is a complete mystery to me why people are still using this monstrosity. Actually,it's not-it's because Ahlfors was a God at Harvard and they're afraid of being struck down by lightening using anything else.I can think of at least a half a dozen texts now that are better then this one. 

Comment: I'm not a huge fan of this book, either...

Comment: 'Elementary Theory of Analytic Functions of One or Several Complex Variables' by Cartan is a far superior text.

Comment: @TheMathemagician, which books would you recommend instead of Ahlfors?

Comment: @FawzyHegab The most up-to-date,complete and user-friendly text on the subject that exists is COMPLEX ANALYSIS by Theodore Gamelin. Requiring only a background in nonrigorous calculus,the book brings one from the basics of complex numbers through analytic functions through differential and integral complex calculus to graduate level topics like Julia and Mandelbrot sets and Runge's theorem. It also includes many applications to geometry and physics, such as Euclidean mappings and fluid dynamics. It also has a several discussions of Riemann surfaces.at different levels. An outstanding book.

Answer (score 11):

Real and Complex Analysis by W. Rudin is a beautiful and extremely well written book which presents the fundamentals of real and complex analysis highlighting the interactions between different results and ideas.

Comment: I'm all for "adult rudin"... but undergraduate? I don't see it. Have you seen it used at the undergraduate level?

Comment: Actually, Rudin has an undergraduate-level book also, the "small Rudin". I learned from it, and it was fine. I loathe the big Rudin, though, even for graduate level. I never managed to learn anything from it; I especially hated the way every proof refers to a million previous results as "Lemma 12.1.8" without mentioning what they actually are. As a result, reading *anything* required flipping through the whole book after every line just to know what he is talking about.

Comment: I don't like either Rudin particularly,to be honest.Adult Rudin tries to put too much into one book.Folland is the same level and is just so much more pleasant to read. 

Comment: Adult Rudin is used for (3rd year) undergraduates at Cambridge.

Answer (score 11):

Spivak, *A Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry.*  There is a nice geometrical philosophy and plenty of motivation.

Comment: Especially the newer version which is typeset in LaTeX! The typesetting of the older version is still charming in its own ugly way, though. Also, I'm not sure if Spivak should count as an undergraduate level book...

Answer (score 10):

As an undergraduate, I loved Shafarevich's book [Basic notions of algebra](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3540612211). This is not a textbook, but gives small beautiful tastes of a broad choice of topics in algebra, emphasizing connections with other fields.

I found it very stimulating, in the sense that every example or overview of some topic in this book made me want to learn more details about it. In fact I became interested in algebraic geometry because of this book.

Comment: The absolute best of scores of algebra books that I've ever read.

Answer (score 10):

Guillemin and Pollack, "Differential Topology"

Comment: Even with the tons of good introductions to differentiable manifolds available these days,Deane-this is STILL one of the very best and well worth the money.

Answer (score 10):

Dummit and Foote's *Abstract Algebra* is an excellent book for learning group theory, ring theory, and module theory.  There's also a section on basic algebraic geometry and homological algebra.

Comment: Galois theory is also covered quite extensively. The Algebraic Geometry section doesn't discuss Projective varieties, so I don't recommend it for AlGeo. However, the problems are ample so also counter-examples.

Comment: From what I've read so far it really is a great book, and the fact that it covers such a major part of basic abstract algebra makes it even greater.

Answer (score 10):

I didn't see any suggested books from the great Russian school of mathematics, here is a brief list of superb, well written, example oriented books:

- *Elements of the Theory of Functions and Functional Analysis* by A. N. Kolmogorov and S. V. Fomin
- *Theory of Functions of a Real Variable* by I. P. Natanson (this I think, it's hard to find)
- *Theory of Functions of a Complex Variable*, Second Edition (3 vol. set) by A. I. Markushevich
- *Elements of Functional Analysis*  by L.A. Lusternik and V.J. Sobolev
- *Problems in Mathematical Analysis* by B. Demidovich
- *Calcul intégral et differentiel* (2 vol. set) by N. Piskounov. In English should be something like *Differential and Integral Calculus*
- *A Course of Mathematical Analysis* (2 vol. set ) S. Nikols'skii
- *Differentialrechnung und Integralrechnung* (3 vol. set), by Gregor M. Fichtenholz. Unfortunately, there is no English translation of this book, only the German translation that it's mentioned. I think this was THE calculus book on Russia. THIS BOOK SHOULD BE TRANSLATED INTO ENGLISH, and I suspect that there is no copyright, it appears around 1959 I think.
- *Mathematical Analysis* (2 vol. set) by Vladimir A. Zorich. This is a very recent book from a great mathematician which is in Moscow university. The book is based upon is lecture.

I have also found a Spanish translation of a book written by S. Banach about "Differential and integral calculus". It is very good as an undergraduate book. The spanish translation (for those who want to search) is *Calculo diferencial e integral*

Books that undergraduate should not touch (in my humble opinion) are books written in bourbaki's style.

Answer (score 10):

[Topics in Algebra](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Topics-Algebra-I-N-Herstein/dp/0471010901/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1274831031&sr=8-1) by I. N. Herstein. A new edition will be coming out this year.

Comment: Herstein is long dead. Would love to know who did the revision and I hope it didn't get watered down in the process. 

Answer (score 10):

Ireland and Rosen, [*A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/038797329X) is a great second course in number theory. In spite of being part of "Graduate Texts in Mathematics" series and unlike Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis* (see a comment above), this is a book at the undergraduate level. It only presupposes undergraduate algebra as in Herstein *Topics in Algebra* or M. Artin's *Algebra*, undergraduate analysis like in Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* and basic number theory. In fact it recalls or proves many of the necessary results in each of those fields. *A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory* bridges the gap between basic number theory (that covers modular arithmetic, Fermat's little theorem and QR) and books like Lang's *Algebraic Number Theory* or Cassels and Fröhlich.

Comment: GREAT  book. The best number theory book for honor students.

Answer (score 9):

I am surprised no one has mentioned Halmos' Naive Set Theory or Finite-Dimensional Vector Spaces or Rudin's Principles of Mathematcal Analysis. There's also Sheldon Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right and Royden's Real Analysis.

Comment: I believe we are supposed to put just one book per answer. It makes it easier to wote up.

Comment: Sheldon Axler (not Steven), for what it's worth.

Answer (score 8):

For discrete mathematics, I would recommend Van Lint-Wilson's "A Course in Combinatorics" as a good introductory text.  It consists of 38 (in my edition) chapters that give (often largely self-contained) introductions to various areas of the field.  Although it doesn't go nearly as in depth as, say, Stanley's "Enumerative Combinatorics" or a text focused solely on graph theory, I found it excellent for giving a broad overview and indicating to me where I wanted to explore deeper.

My one caveat would be that some chapters require background in either linear algebra or basic group theory, though those are easily skippable due to the structure of the book.

Answer (score 8):

*Basic Algebra* by Jacobson.

Comment: Volume I is a great guide for the advanced undergraduate, but I think that volume II is beyond what all but the most sophisticated undergraduates can deal with.

Comment: I agree: volume II is harder.

Answer (score 7):

General geometry: Coxeter, Introduction to Geometry.

Not so much a textbook as a collection of essays (in particular, it doesn't have exercises), but all of the essays are instructive and enlightening.

Answer (score 6):

Ok, this is not a single book, but I have often found books from the Springer Undergraduate Mathematics Series (SUMS) to be excellent. Here is a [list of titles](http://www.springer.com/series/3423?detailsPage=titles).

Answer (score 6):

Another one I like is "An introduction to Lie algebras." by Erdmann and Wildon.

Answer (score 6):

*[Galois Theory](https://books.google.com/books?id=G_A8HciIro4C&pg=PP1&dq=ian+galois+theory&ei=PM_YSsYqiIaVBKGQ4JIB#v=onepage&q=&f=false)* by Ian Stewart is excellent. The third edition is quite different from the second and includes many more problems.

---

Comment: it has certain amount of typos (reflected by other students in bard). 

Answer (score 6):

I am surprised this has not been mentioned before (is it too advanced?):

Bott and Tu, *Differential forms in algebraic topology.*

The best introduction to de Rham cohomology, spectral sequences, characteristic classes from the algebraic point of view, and countless other topics.

Comment: Certainly true,but unless your undergraduates are in Germany or at Harvard,that book is definitely too tough for this list.

Comment: Hey, I was an undergraduate in Moscow. Does that count?

Comment: ... and seeing that Hatcher, Serre, Jacobson, Alperin, and Evans have been featured (some at the very top), I don't agree that it's "too tough for this list".

Comment:  Yes-and with the POSSIBLE exception of Hatcher,none of them belong on a general reading list for undergraduates,Victor. You studied in a VERY strong program and you need to be a bit more mindful of that when making such lofty aspairations for mere mortals.And that goes for quite a few people in here.

Answer (score 6):

Algebra: Chapter 0, Paolo Aluffi

Best book on algebra I've had my hands on yet, and I love how it uses category theory. I wouldn't mind having a course taught from this one. Topics from group theory all the way through field theory, linear algebra, and homology. This book deserves more attention!

[https://www.amazon.com/Algebra-Chapter-Graduate-Studies-Mathematics/dp/0821847813/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1278799249&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0821847813)

Comment: Terrific book for first year graduate algebra or honors undergraduate.

Answer (score 5):

Searcóid: Elements of Abstract Analysis. I loved this book as an undergraduate, for many reasons, but mainly because it gave me an idea of the unity of mathematics. It starts from the axioms of set theory and takes you  all the way to C*-algebras and the Gelfand-Naimark theorem. Here's the [Google Books page](https://books.google.com/books?id=c3ChND-I42wC&dq=%22elements+of+abstract+analysis%22&source=gbs_navlinks_s).

Comment: <pedant> The name is actually "Ó Searcóid" (cf. names like O'Grady, which are Anglicised versions of the same form).</pedant>

Anyway, nice choice


Answer (score 5):

Jaenich: "Topology"

Introduces the concepts of point set topology ("paracompact" and all this stuff) motivating each via examples which are rigorously defined but also drawn. Other advantage: It is short!

Comment: It's also great for someone trying to learn mathematical German! (not that that's terribly useful anymore... ><)

Comment: I particularly love his proof of the Urysohn's lemma: the presentation of the main idea of the proof is brilliant, simple and clear.

Comment: I am SO totally pumped people are finally rediscovering this classic!

Answer (score 5):

Apostol "Calculus"

Answer (score 5):

Bartle "The Elements of Integration and Lebesgue Measure"

Comment: Excellent book, especially for an undergrad course.  One of my favorite parts of the book was his diagrams for modes of convergence: http://www.johndcook.com/modes_of_convergence.html

Answer (score 5):

I'm a big fan of John Hubbard's "Vector Calculus, Linear Algebra and Differential Forms" text.  I was a TA for the course twice at Cornell and was amazed at how well it went.  The text has an extremely pleasant "zest" to it. When Hubbard asked me to take a look at it my first response was the text is "overflowing with the spirit of calculus".  I still believe that. I have a hard time containing my praise.

The main problem with the text is that it's so engrossing.  It places more demands on the student than a traditional service course text would ever consider.  But it's also *far* more rewarding.  At Cornell it was taught as a branch of their traditional calculus sequence -- it was a course that was earmarked for keener students, mostly from other departments.

In short, if you want to have physics, engineering and economics students appreciating the derivative as a linear approximation, thinking Lipschitz bounds for functions are cool, being interested in the computation of norms of linear operators, etc, this is a great resource.

Comment: There  are "undergraduate" texts that are so deep with ideas and concepts that anyone of any level can learn from them. Books like this are Spivak's classic "Calculus On Manfolds",Janich's "Topology",Hoffman's "Analysis In Euclidean Space" and more recently McCleary's "A First Course In Topology:Continuity And Dimension". Hubbard and Hubbard CERTAINLY belongs in that select group. 

Comment: John Hubbard is DA MAN!!!

Answer (score 5):

Karen Smith et al., [An Invitation to Algebraic Geometry](https://books.google.com/books?id=8zQYxx7PjqsC)

Comment: Since I haven't looked at this book but might be interested...

This book is "undergraduate level" for whom?  Presumably, many Harvard senior math majors would be able to tackle it.  How many senior math majors at a mid-tier public research university?  mid-tier liberal arts college? compass point state college?

Comment: (off-topic comment deleted)

Answer (score 4):

Real Mathematical Analysis by Charles Pugh

Comment: Thank you,someone finally mentioned this book.I'm hoping it supplants baby Rudin eventually.I affectionally call it "Rudin Done Right".

Answer (score 4):

Lectures on Linear Algebra by I. M. Gel'fand

Answer (score 4):

Also, I just started this book and absolutely love it

[Geometry: Euclid and Beyond, Hartshorne](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387986502)

Answer (score 4):

Fraleigh's "A First Course in Abstract Algebra"

[https://www.amazon.com/First-Course-Abstract-Algebra-7th/dp/0201763907](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201763907)

Answer (score 4):

For a thorough introduction on Partial Differential Equations, read [L.C. Evans, "Partial Differential Equations"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821807722). Features both linear and nonlinear equations.

Comment: that book is very good. 

For a 1st or 2nd year undergraduate, perhaps a slightly more accessible book is Haberman - "Applied Partial Differential equations"; admitted it is "applied", but it overlaps heavily with pure PDEs and has many "pure" techniques. 

Comment:  Evan's is a great GRADUATE level text. Most undergraduates would be like,"huh?" A much better choice is the long out of print Robert L.Street's "Analysis And Solution Of Partial Differential Equations".

Comment: @Andrew L: while the book is clearly meant for graduate students, it is also suitable for undergrads, especially the first chapters (and omitting the "omit on first reading" parts). With appropriate supervision, even some of the nonlinear chapters can be read by undergrads.

Comment: @Martijn,those would have to be VERY good undergraduates indeed and you'd have to be REALLY selective with it. 

Comment: That's quite a hefty book.  I think undergrads would be better served by covering a less ambitious book rather than not getting very far into Evans.

Answer (score 4):

For a long time, [Kolmogorov-Fomin's *Introductory Real Analysis*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486612260) was my standard for a great mahtematics textbook. I can't imagine a better introduction to serious analysis.

The translation I'm linking to is very good, and includes excercises (the original has many fewer), but it is incomplete (it's missing the chapter on Fourier Series). So if you can read Russian, I recommend you get the original.

Comment: You know,it's interesting you should approve so strongly of the Silverman translation of the Kolomogrov/Fomin text,Ilya. A lot of Russian mathematicians I've brought it up to tell me Silverman should be hanged for ruining such a classic.Guess you can't please everyone. 

Answer (score 4):

From the quick look I've had, not much representation theory has been mentioned so here goes for undergrad level rep theory (perhaps suitable for 3rd/4th year in a standard sequence of undergraduate study), roughly in the order of difficulty (from easiest to hardest):

- James & Liebeck - "Representations and Characters of Groups" (a very good introduction)
- Sagan - "The symmetric group: representations, combinatorial algorithms, and symmetric functions"; (the first two chapters here at least are representation theory) OR James & Kerber - "Representation Theory of the Symmetric Group" (this one includes some modular representations of $S_n$)
- Alperin - "Local Representation Theory" (basically, modular representation theory)
- Hall - "Lie groups, Lie Algebras and Representation Theory" (a solid introduction to Lie theory); for a more advanced perspective Harris & Fulton - "Representation Theory: A first course" (but it could be slightly terse at points, but not necessarily)

For algebraic geometry, the one book I'd suggest is "Algebraic Geometry: A first course" by Joe Harris, very nice and full of examples. For algebraic number theory, a very good introduction is Janusz - "Algebraic Number Fields" (followed perhaps by Childress - "Class Field Theory", or Silverman - "The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves" to go in a slightly different direction).

Answer (score 4):

Here is an undergraduate level math book recommendation from an early undergrad's position:

I like "Linear Algebra Done Right". I've looked at a bunch of books on linear algebra, and the usual matrix approach is to me a big turn-off when what you're really interested in is the abstract machinery of transformations between vector spaces. I'm not a research mathematician. In fact, I don't even study linear algebra yet, but as a student of mathematics that like algebra, spaces, maps and all that good stuff, I find this to be a very readable account of linear algebra.

There are more abstract books on the subject, and my impression is that LADR prepares you for the next level way before you're usually "allowed to" by other accounts like Lax etc. The trade-off is that LADR is not a book for engineers, but this would be a sad world for a mathematician if that was something he had to worry about (in his spare time). Great for self-study. Reads like a novel. I'd probably prefer it if Axler used sets for span and bases instead of lists, but that's something you'll probably be able to shake off with the next book you read on the subject.

Comment: See the other answer on this book for my comments.


Comment: I'm not sure I agree your comments warrants a vote-down for this one. I still think it's a good book (for people who wants to learn mathematics for the benefit of mathematics), and my position for what I want the book to do is clear and I think it accomplishes it.

Answer (score 4):

*Visual Complex Analysis* by Tristan Needham is *awesome*!

Comment: In fact, there are others that agree with you: the book is already in the list!

Answer (score 4):

[Linear Algebra / Hoffman & Kunze](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0135367972) - A book that truly develops linear algebra in a gradual manner. It starts with a basic discussion of systems of linear equations, matrices, Gaussian elimination, etc. and gradually progresses to the more abstract theory. Eventually it even touches upon subjects such as tensor products, the exterior algebra and the Grassmann ring. In short, it manages to cover a lot of linear algebra in a very leisurely and clear manner. I think that this is the quintessential example of a how an undergraduate level math book should be written. The only thing I don't like about it is the fact that quotient spaces aren't mentioned throughout the book (they're mentioned in the appendix, though).

Comment: I'd LOVE to teach a one year honors course in linear algebra using the union of both H&K and Strang. A truly balanced course that shows how both aspects of the subject-theory and applications-are equally important.

Answer (score 3):

Alexandre Stefanov keeps an extensive [list](http://mathbooks.110mb.com/mylist.php) ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20100706111909/http://mathbooks.110mb.com/mylist.php), [another link](http://www.trillia.com/online-math/algebra.html)) of free math books / lecture notes. The list is divided according to subject and updated frequently. I have found some very nice books there.

Comment: that link doesn't work!  could you try posting it again?

Comment: Thanks for letting me know of the broken link. It now works.

Comment: Link which is currently working: http://www.trillia.com/online-math/

Answer (score 3):

An Introduction to Manifolds by Loring W. Tu

[https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Manifolds-Universitext-Loring-W/dp/0387480986/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1256082981&sr=1-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387480986)

Answer (score 3):

Riemannian Geometry: A Beginner's Guide by Frank Morgan

[https://www.amazon.com/Riemannian-Geometry-Beginners-Frank-Morgan/dp/1568810733/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1256083041&sr=1-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1568810733)

I love this book!

Answer (score 3):

Subject: FUNCTIONAL ANALYSIS

Erwin Kreyszig

**Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications**

Answer (score 3):

E. Hairer, G. Wanner: Analysis by its history for an introduction to real and numerical analysis from a historical point of view.

Answer (score 3):

Kock, Vainsencher: An invitation to Quantum Cohomology.

Written in the most friendly and motivating style I have ever seen in a book. Almost has no prerequisites: You should that there exists something like algebraic varieties - without having to know any technical details - and that P^1 is such a thing. Everything else is provided in easy exercises or the text. It gives an excellent intuition about the subject with lots of outlooks on a field of current research, and at the same time manages to be easily undergraduate readable.

Answer (score 3):

[Lebesgue Integration on Euclidean Space / Frank Jones](https://books.google.com/books?id=3U7tresTD1AC&printsec=frontcover&dq=lebesgue+integration+on+euclidean+space&source=bl&ots=ZFuDMZPPWg&sig=ypt3ZcVvmdowz8uUXc_aNcHGCA8&hl=en&ei=Psc4TJfmO47vOZ-IsYoK&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CBoQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false) - an extremely readable book on Lebesgue theory on $\mathbb{R}^n$ (lots of figures and geometric intuition). He constructs Lebesgue measure in a very down-to-earth manner, much more explicitly than other more abstract constructions (via Caratheodory's extension theorem or Riesz's representation theorem). In my experience, it's best to first study Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and only then point out that it's merely one instance of the general theory of measures, which is the way this book is written. It can't compare with the "tougher" books on measure theory (e.g. Big Rudin) since it doesn't discuss the Radon-Nikodym theorem and many other important theorems in measure theory, but then again the book is clearly intended for an undergraduate audience, and as for Lebesgue theory on Euclidean spaces, it provides a pretty complete picture.

Comment: One of the best introductions to the subject out there. Should be on everyone's must-read list and great collateral reading with the more intense introductions like Big Rudin or Folland.

Answer (score 2):

There is a good list [here](http://hk.geocities.com/mathphyweb/puremath.htm) ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20091019171551/http://hk.geocities.com/mathphyweb/puremath.htm)), divided by subject, that also contains many links to freely available textbooks and lecture notes.

Comment: can't see anything here - where is the list?

Comment: ...perhabs it is because I don't speak chinese...

Answer (score 2):

Kelley, *General Topology*

Answer (score 2):

Introduction to Topology: Pure and Applied, by Adams and Franzosa.
The figures in the book are beautiful, the problems are good, and the applications are good (and unusual) to see in an undergraduate text.

Comment: That sounds like a nice book.  It's pretty expensive, unfortunately.  

Answer (score 2):

Linear Algebra and Its Applications by Gilbert Strang. You can also watch his video lectures at MIT [OpenCourseWare](http://ocw.mit.edu/OcwWeb/Mathematics/18-06Spring-2005/CourseHome/index.htm)

Answer (score 2):

"Introduction to Mathematical Logic" by Ebbinghaus, Flum and Thomas

Careful introduction, addresses many doubts that one might have about why one does logic in this way and not some other, e.g. whether one is doing something circular when formulating set theory in 1st order logic, or e.g. it proves Lindstroem's Theorem, that says that classical 1st order logic has the highest power of expressability among the logics with completeness and Loewenheim-Skolem.

Answer (score 2):

Metric Spaces by Mícheál Ó Searcóid

[https://www.amazon.com/Metric-Spaces-Springer-Undergraduate-Mathematics/dp/1846283698/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1256082496&sr=1-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1846283698)

It's an exhaustive introduction analysis at the level of the metric space that's well worth reading.

Answer (score 2):

Introduction to Analysis by William R. Wade

[https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Analysis-4th-William-Wade/dp/0132296381/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1256082707&sr=1-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132296381)

This is a good transition from undergraduate calculus to analysis.

Answer (score 2):

Godement "Analysis" (I,II,III,IV)
[https://www.amazon.com/Analysis-Convergence-Elementary-functions-Universitext/dp/3540059237](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3540059237)

"... The content is quite classical ... [...] The treatment is less classical: precise although unpedantic (rather far from the definition-theorem-corollary-style), it contains many interesting commentaries of epistemological, pedagogical, historical and even political nature. [...] The author gives frequent interesting hints on recent developments of mathematics connected to the concepts which are introduced. The Introduction also contains comments that are very unusual in a book on mathematical analysis, going from pedagogy to critique of the French scientific-military-industrial complex, but the sequence of ideas is introduced in such a way that readers are less surprised than they might be.

Answer (score 2):

How about an **anti**-recommendation?  Someone in another answer mentioned Steven Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right*.  My comment, not as someone who has used this book in a class, but as someone who has taught the students from this class during the following term:   It doesn't prepare the students to use linear algebra in engineering, in physics, in chemistry, or even in branches of mathematics other than abstract algebra.

Comment: I suppose the correct thing to ask then is: what WOULD you use?

Not to be confrontational, just that the standard around these parts is pretty poor, and Axler is considered much better.

Also, could you explain what they're not teaching? I'd be interested to know!

Thanks!

Comment: What they're not teaching?

Here is a true story:  Students took an HONORS course in linear algebra.  Next term, I was to teach these same students an honors course in differential equations.  We started with linear ODEs.  I work out the standard formulas.  After class, a student comes to me and says:  "I asked the others, and none of us has ever heard of Cramer's Rule."  So, I added some exercises on Cramer's Rule for them.  But I was so amazed by this that I found out what textbook had been used (it was "Linear Algebra Done Right") and verified that there is no mention of Cramer's Rule.



Comment: Then how about "Linear Algebra Done Wrong", available for free at http://www.math.brown.edu/~treil/papers/LADW/LADW.html?

Comment: @Gerald: I'm not sure omission of Cramer's Rule is such a big deal.  Cramer's Rule is helpful for solving small linear systems (2 or 3 unknowns) since there are useful heuristics for calculating the determinants of 2x2 and 3x3 matrices, but Gaussian elimination is a more powerful and general algorithm for solving linear systems.

Comment: * Then how about "Linear Algebra Done Wrong", *
Looks good, actually.  Suitable for students interested in other branches of mathematics!


Comment: The book is for students already familiar with matrix algebra, so this is not a valid criticism of the book.

Comment: The best LA book for students at the honors level I've seen is Friedberg,Insel and Spenser. Very comprehensive and rigorous with a lot of nice examples and exercises. Curtis' book is very nice too and has a better treatment of Jordan canonical form.

Answer (score 2):

General Topology, by Stephen Willard

https://books.google.com/books?id=-o8xJQ7Ag2cC&lpg=PP1&dq=stephen%20willard&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q=&f=false

Answer (score 2):

*A Field Guide to Algebra* by Antoine Chambert Loir. Covers a surprising amount of material considering the short length and minimal prerequisites

Answer (score 2):

"TOPOLOGY WITHOUT TEARS" by SIDNEY A. MORRIS is a very nice introduction in topological spaces theory, I think.

Comment: Available online: http://uob-community.ballarat.edu.au/~smorris/topology.htm

Answer (score 2):

[Geroch, Mathematical Physics](https://books.google.com/books?id=wp2A7ZBUwDgC)

Don't be scared by the title: it teaches algebra, topology and measure theory, using category-theoretic language.

Comment: Indeed, that's a nice one!

Answer (score 2):

"Differential Calculus on Normed Linear Banach Spaces" by Kalyan Mukherjee.

The author is a prof at the Indian Statistical Institute (Kolkata)

This is an amazing book which introduces differential calculus in arbitrary finite dimensional spaces (thinking of the derivative as the Jacobian) as the next leap from the Apostol and Rudin level and also build in topological ideas. It then goes into manifold theory and shows how to compute tangents to curves inside lie groups. It has nice sections of things like differentiating the determinant function and the matrix multiplication function and inverse function theorem and idea of equivalence of norms.

I would strongly recommend this book to an undergrad after he/she has done the Apostol/Rudin level of calculus.

"Calculus on Manifolds" by Spivak and "Differential geometry and Lie groups" by Kumaresan are two other good books which can be read alongside it.

Answer (score 2):

I liked [Elements of Abstract Algebra](http://books.google.ca/books?id=bj1kOY8gOfcC&dq=elements+of+abstract+algebra&printsec=frontcover&source=bl&ots=sMDMivxMQ6&sig=5XAar4HPSaqw0XRPBwt0Om4ibhA&hl=en&ei=SKcuS4fEJsbilAePleCkBw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CAoQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=&f=false) by Allan Clark, which is mainly a problem book with a moderate amount of exposition, but the problems are so well-chosen that a diligent undergraduate student working through all of them will come out with a solid knowledge of group theory, classical ring theory, and Galois theory.

Answer (score 2):

I think that *Linear Algebra* by Friedberg, Insel, and Spence is a spectacular linear algebra book. It gets straight to the point, it provides a worked out example or two exactly when they're needed, and it has lots of interesting exercises.

There are way too many gigantic linear algebra books with colour pictures and contrived examples which often seem to obfuscate the concepts being introduced. In my mind this book is 'the mathematician's linear algebra book'; clean and concise.

Comment: I second this choice.It balances rigorous theory and applications better then any book on the subject I've seen. Charles Curtis's old classic is also excellent and it has a much better discussion of the Jordan form and decomposition algorithm. 

Answer (score 2):

For (applied) ODEs: *[Nonlinear dynamics and chaos](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0738204536)* by Steven Strogatz.

A very inspiring book! The explanations are crystal clear with lots of pictures. And it's funny too – the "Romeo and Juliet" illustration of 2-dimensional linear systems (Section 5.3) is a classic.

Answer (score 2):

Atiyah and MacDonald, *Introduction to Commutative Algebra*

Comment: Do you really think this book is undergraduate level?  

Comment: I feel that in the case of AM, this criticism misses the mark: although not everyone is an algebraist, commutative algebra is a valid subject of undergraduate study (i.e. not "too deep")! The book is very clearly written (incomparably better than van der Waerden) and is good for self-study for problem-oriented people. Nonetheless, I wish that at the time I had the courage to read Zariski and Samuel instead: in spite of being 2 volumes, it is so much more relaxed because the authors take care to $\mathit{explain}$ the material, in multiple ways, and offer both breadth and depth of perspective.

Comment: @Victor I totally agree on Zariski and Samuels.But if you're going to invest that much time in a tome that lengthy,then you may as well get Eisenbud.In any event,all these books will be too difficult for any but the best undergraduates,I'm sorry. 

Comment: Right.  I definitely think Reid's book is at a much more manageable level than A&M.  

Comment: The second paragraph of the introduction begins, "This book grew out of a series of lectures given to third year undergraduates ..."  The authors also point out that their book is not intended as a substitute to the Zariski-Samuel or Bourbaki books. 

Comment: @Kiochi The exact line: "This book grew out of a series of lectures given to third year undergraduates at OXFORD UNIVERSITY......" Which would be first year graduate students at any ordinary but decent university.Again-WHICH undergraduates you mean is very important. 

Comment: Andrew, this is as much a function of time as it is a function of space: the lectures were presumably given in the 1960s, when people didn't shy from teaching and learning abstract mathematics.

Comment: I have to agree that Atiyah and MacDonald is one of the best written textbooks in mathematics. There are very few proofs which exceed a given length (in part due to the fact that these proofs are condensed for the overall readability of the book), but it really is not that hard a book if you are familiar with the basics of algebra. Personally I feel that if you have some desire to become an algebraist in your undergraduate education, you should at least attempt to read Atiyah and MacDonald. The same goes for any potential algebraic geometer but to a lesser extent.

Comment: (I deleted an off-topic comment.)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend Walter Rudin's classic text entitled *Real and Complex Analysis* for the mathematically mature undergraduate student. (Of course, this should really only be read after one has familiarity with most of Rudin's earlier textbook: *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*.)

The beautiful thing about this book is that nearly every example or result stated by Rudin is used in "the big picture". As you progress through the book, you really start to appreciate the magic Rudin has used to weave together analysis in a manner that is rarely done in other textbooks.

While Rudin states in his preface that the textbook is intended as a first year graduate course on the subject of analysis, I believe that it is quite possible for a mathematically mature undergraduate to follow it. There is no assumption in the book that the reader has any familiarity with linear algebra, abstract algebra, general topology etc. beyond that which was covered in the first seven chapters of his earlier book, but realistically one would like to have at least mastered the basics of these areas before attempting to delve deeper into the analysis covered in this book. (There is a chapter on Banach algebras, but all the necessary abstract algebra here is developed from scratch.)

The textbook is indeed challenging with plenty of exercises, but it is not something with which a student with the correct prerequisites should have tremendous difficulty. Furthermore, if a student can successfully read most of the book, he is well-equipped to go deeper into most branches of modern analysis, and should find the other classic texts in the subject, for instance Royden's *Real Analysis*, Bartle's *The Elements of Integration and Lebesgue Measure* etc., very easy to follow.

The Amazon page for this book can be found [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0070542341).

Comment: You are being incredibly optimistic here,Amitesh. See my comments below. Why don't you recommend Lang's ALGEBRA to sophomores without linear algebra while you're at it? "Undergraduate texts".At Yale or Harvard,MAYBE-and even THAT'S a stretch. 

Comment: However, even if, by current standards, undergraduates are not expected to be able to read a book of this sort, I believe that it is something that is readily accessible if you are willing to put in the appropriate hard work. For instance, as I noted above, the only prerequisites for this book lie within 200 or so pages of mathematics "above calculus". (Rudin's earlier textbook.) But perhaps *I am* being optimistic now that I think about it ...

Comment: For UNDERGRADUATES,Yes,you are,Amitesh.Then again,if you're a first year graduate student and you CAN'T read Rudin-not find it difficult,literally it's beyond your ability-you need to seriously consider a change of career.

Comment: But just out of interest, in case you know, is Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis* actually taught at many universities at the graduate level? My perception is that Royden's and Bartle's texts are the "classics" but I have not actually read them. (I am reading Rudin, instead.) And it indeed seems that some universities use Royden for an introductory real analysis course, and Alfhors for an introductory complex analysis course. However, Royden is, in my opinion, too basic if you wish to purse analysis in some depth so if Rudin is not used, do you know what is?

Comment: I apologize: I meant Ahlfors instead of "Alfhors" in the most recent comment.

Answer (score 2):

Algebraic Theory of Numbers, by Pierre Samuel

Assumes only elementary knowledge of group and ring theory (even less than a complete undergraduate course which covers Galois theory) and develops algebraic number theory, a beautiful subject which puts much elementary number theory into an interesting perspective.

Answer (score 2):

I would also recommend the book entitled *Analysis on Manifolds* by James Munkres. I think that this is a good undergraduate textbook in mathematics for any student wishing to pursue multivariable calculus in greater depth. My only complaint is that Munkres often chooses to include details which can be seen easily after a little bit of thought. Perhaps this can be viewed as an effort to show the student how to "properly do analysis": doing analysis, just like doing any other branch of mathematics, requires you to carefully apply definitions and theorems, and it is important for the student to appreciate this early in his/her mathematical learning.

That said, the book is an excellent text overall for "advanced calculus". The student will need to be familiar with single variable analysis and perhaps some linear algebra. (Even a rudimentary knowledge of linear algebra will do since Munkres develops most of the necessary theory from scratch.)

Roughly speaking, the book splits into two parts. The first part covers most of the results students see when doing multivariable calculus that are stated "without proof" in their texts. For example, "the equality of the mixed partials", "double integrals can be done in any order", "a bounded function is Riemann integral if and only if it is continuous almost everywhere", "the change of variables theorem" etc., are (very) imprecise forms of some of the results Munkres establishes.

In the second part of the book, manifolds and their theory are introduced. Thus, for example, a rudimentary introduction to tensors is given, and this is supplemented by the basic theory of differential forms, the De Rham groups (of the punctured plane), Stokes' theorem etc.

I think that the exposition could be tightened: if you actually pick up the book and really make an effort to read it, it is quite possible to finish the first half of the book in the space of a week (that is, approximately 200 pages in a week) simply because certain topics are explained in more detail (at least in my opinion) than necessary. (One example is Munkres' proof of the linearity, monotonicity, additivity etc. of the Riemann integral. This is proved in three contexts *separately*: the case of the integral over a rectangle, that over a bounded set, and that of improper integrals, when essentially the proofs can be left as relatively easy exercises in some cases.)

As the above comments suggest, I think that this is an excellent book for undergraduate students, but perhaps less so for graduate students. (Spivak's *Calculus on Manifolds* is good for both undergraduate and graduate students, in my opinion, but *some people* may suggest that it is too hard for undergraduates.) And after reading this book, you should have more than enough preparation to read more advanced texts such as William Boothby's *An Introduction to Differentiable Manifolds and Riemannian Geometry*.

Comment: I really like Munkres,too. My one complaint with it is I just wish Munkres had included some physical applications of this material,such as in differential equations or electromagnetism.

Comment: Spivak's book is somehow too concise for undergraduate. I prefer Munkres. And Janich&Brocker's introduction to diff. geometry might serve as a reading material if we want to make the flavor.

Answer (score 1):

Since Numerical Mathematics has not been covered, I would recommend the following

Introduction to Numerical Analysis by Stoer et. al.  [https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Numerical-Analysis-J-Stoer/dp/038795452X/ref=sr_1_14?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1255807973&sr=8-14](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/038795452X)

Answer (score 1):

Linear Algebra: With Applications 
Otto Bretscher

Used at Carleton College – nice explanations, and quite a few proofs. Presents information primarily by providing examples, definitions/axioms and then proofs.

Comment: Taught out of it several times, didn't like it at all. Also, the smugglers used to "motivate" (hah!) linear transformations in the first edition turned into evildoers in the second. I dread to even think who they've metamorphized into now.  

Answer (score 1):

I had many trials and these are in my opinion the best for an introductory, undergraduate level:

ODEs: Holzner: Differential Equations for Dummies 
PDEs: Farlow: Partial Differential Equations for Scientists and Engineers

Answer (score 1):

Applied Linear Algebra, by B. Noble and J.W. Daniel, https://www.amazon.co.uk/Applied-Linear-Algebra-Ben-Noble/dp/0130412600/ref=sr_1_14?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1256927879&sr=1-14 .

Answer (score 1):

G. J. O. Jameson: Topology and Normed Spaces for an introduction to functional analysis from a topological point of view.

Answer (score 1):

lindsey childs *a concrete introduction to abstract algebra*

[here maybe](https://books.google.com/books?id=rUApHgaTVx0C&dq=concrete+introduction+to+higher+algebra&printsec=frontcover&source=bn&hl=en&ei=KVr0Sqe4CcLOlAfs__ClAw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CBUQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=&f=false).

Comment: It's a bit obsolete by now.

Answer (score 1):

Strichartz, *The Way of Analysis*

Herstein, *Abstract Algebra*

Comment: I also like Herstein's Abstract Algebra.

Answer (score 1):

Milnor's book "Dynamics in One Complex Variable: Introductory Lectures".  An early version is available from his website.  Suitable for advanced undergraduates, graduate students, and mathematicians.

http://www.math.sunysb.edu/cgi-bin/preprint.pl?ims90-5 ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20140110181212/http://www.math.stonybrook.edu/preprints/ims90-5.pdf))

Answer (score 1):

Most readers here will not be able to appreciate them for a simple reason, but my favorite beginners' Analysis text is that by [Bröcker](http://www.mathematik.uni-regensburg.de/broecker/index.htm) ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20130407173813/http://www.mathematik.uni-regensburg.de/broecker/index.htm)).  No-nonsense, concise, with a slight orientation towards topology.

Answer (score 1):

Hugo Steinhaus https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hugo_Steinhaus book "Mathematical Kaleidoscope". It is kind of mathematical trivia sometimes very deep;-) It is not for learning math but for learning how to learn math in fun way.

Answer (score 1):

*Complex Variables: Harmonic and Analytic Functions* by Francis J. Flanigan

A nice little Dover paperback which turns the standard course on complex variables on its head. It begins by doing some multivariable calculus in the plane and harmonic functions, then proceeds to talk about complex numbers and to build analytic functions.

Answer (score 1):

Siegfried Bosch, Lineare Algebra

It's a very elegant, concise but beautifully written approach to Linear Algebra, and I love it.

Unfortunately for people who don't speak German, it has never been translated.

Answer (score 1):

I plan to post a complete reading list for undergraduates and graduate students at my blog this summer with my commentaries,but here's one I think that's available online and doesn't get nearly enough credit despite the fame of it's author: Gilbert Strang's *Calculus*. I wouldn't use anything else for a regular,non-honors calculus course. Carefully written,beautifully motivated with TONS of creative and SIGNIFICANT applications.
I hope one day Strang finds the time to write a second edition-I have a list of improvements to suggest.

Answer (score 1):

[Linear Algebra with Differential Equations: 
Bentley and Cooke 1973](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0030802997)

Answer (score 1):

[A Concrete Approach to Abstract Algebra](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/048663647X) by W. W. Sawyer ($6 on Amazon!)

Though it goes a bit slow at times, it is by far the simplest, most intuitive book on Abstract Algebra in existence.  Written for the non-mathematician, it does a great job of teaching the subject in simple, easy-to-understand prose.  I couldn't put it down!

There are also two chapters on linear algebra, leading up to the final chapters, *"vectors over fields"* and *"fields regarded as vector-spaces"*.

Answer (score 1):

Introduction to Analytic Number Theory - Tom M. Apostol.

When I bought this I really didn't want to put it down. It's a great book for exciting one's interest in the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Real Analysis, by Frank Morgan.
The chapters are short and very directed. The proofs are written well. The exercises are well-selected. The book is written at a level accessible for most students.

Answer (score 0):

Vinogradov's Elements of Number Theory - the problems more so than the text itself.