# Free, high quality mathematical writing online?

Tags: books, big-list

I often use the internet to find resources for learning new mathematics and due to an explosion in online activity, there is always plenty to find.  Many of these turn out to be somewhat unreadable because of writing quality, organization or presentation.

I recently found out that "The Elements of Statistical Learning' by Hastie, Tibshirani and Friedman was available free online: http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/ .  It is a really well written book at a high technical level.  Moreover, this is the second edition which means the book has already gone through quite a few levels of editing.

I was quite amazed to see a resource like this available free online.

Now, my question is, are there more resources like this?  Are there free mathematics books that have it all: well-written, well-illustrated, properly typeset and so on?

Now, on the one hand, I have been saying 'book' but I am sure that good mathematical writing online is not limited to just books.  On the other hand, I definitely don't mean the typical journal article.  It's hard to come up with good criteria on this score, but I am talking about writing that is reasonably lengthy, addresses several topics and whose purpose is essentially pedagogical.

If so, I'd love to hear about them.  Please suggest just one resource per comment so we can vote them up and provide a link!

Comment: There is a whole database of freely available books at http://www.e-booksdirectory.com/mathematics.php; I'm making this a comment since it's not one specific volume.

Comment: There are several links, both to specific free books and to databases, in a related question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/761?sort=votes#sort-top

Comment: A list which I don't think is mentioned in the other question is here: http://people.math.gatech.edu/~cain/textbooks/onlinebooks.html

Comment: I know there is some overlap with other questions but I wanted this to be a list of the very best writing, presentation etc that are freely available rather than just online class notes.  There are some published books that I probably wouldn't put on this list.  Thanks to everybody that has made suggestions.

Comment: @Kim: please make posts like this (anything where you say "one answer per post") community wiki in the future by checking the "community wiki" box when you're composing the question. I've converted this one to community wiki.

Comment: Please, add them to http://mathonline.andreaferretti.it/ too. :-)

Comment: http://lib.org.by/_djvu/M_Mathematics/

Comment: As a general remark, publishers have become fairly open to the idea of their books becoming available freely on authors' webpages. Not for undergrad-level textbooks though. :(

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[John Baez's stuff](http://www.math.ucr.edu/home/baez/) is a fantastic resource for learning about - well, whatever John Baez is interested in, but fortunately that's a lot of interesting stuff.  Scroll down for a link to TWF as well as his expository articles.

Comment: A million times seconded. John Baez has an incredible knack for explaining very abstract stuff in a very intuitive way; "Read John Baez!" has become something of a mantra of mine lately.

Answer (score 56):

The wonderful [webpage of Milne](http://www.jmilne.org/math/) has books/lectures notes on a wide variety of topics, including Algebraic geometry, Etale cohomology, Class field theory, ...

Comment: And since JS Milne has become a MathOverflow user: A big Thank you! - just in case you are reading this...

Comment: Seconded to JS Milne!

Comment: I have a lot of respect for mathematicians such as J.S. Milne and Allen Hatcher who disseminate their work widely and freely.

Answer (score 50):

Everybody probably knows about this already, but Allen Hatcher's textbook on [Algebraic Topology](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATpage.html) is excellent - clear, well-written, neatly typeset.  It takes the student from basic concepts like homotopy equivalence all the way through to things like higher homotopy groups, obstruction theory and representability.

(His partially-written books on [K-Theory](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/VBKT/VBpage.html) and [Spectral Sequences](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/SSAT/SSATpage.html) are also worth a look.)

Answer (score 40):

I'm sort of surprised nobody has mentioned [Terry Tao's blog](http://terrytao.wordpress.com) yet. I think it definitely belongs in this list.

Comment: It certainly does,Darsh. : ) 

Answer (score 33):

The second edition of [generatingfunctionology](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html) by Herbert Wilf is freely available online and is one of my favorite math books ever. It's one of the books that made me fall in love with combinatorics (the other being the Bollobas Graph Theory book).

Answer (score 28):

The wonderful book ["A=B"](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html), by Marko Petkovsek, Herbert Wilf and Doron Zeilberger, is available freely online, thanks to their publisher AK Peters.

If you've ever wondered how to prove identities for q-multinomials and friends, well, the summary of this book is that computers now know how to do it, and you shouldn't bother anymore.

Comment: The preface that Donald Knuth wrote for A=B is terrific too! "Science is what we understand well enough to explain to a computer. Art is everything else we do. [\ldots] Science advances whenever an Art becomes a Science. And the state of the Art advances too, because people always leap into new territory once they have understood more about the old."



Answer (score 23):

I was hoping that someone had posted [Keith Conrad's expository stuff](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/). Twice this week I've searched for an example in algebraic number theory (it is somewhat surprising how few of these there are in the books I own) and found the perfect answer on that page. The papers are remarkable for their high number of carefully chosen examples, just enough of which are worked out for the reader.

Answer (score 22):

Many know Hatchers Book, but few know the nice [Concise Course in Algebraic Topology by J.P.May](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/CONCISE/ConciseRevised.pdf), which discusses, aside the standard stuff, Groupoids, Higher Homotopy and all that in a very brief and modern fashion. I think this is the book to read (for free) after/between Hatchers book.

There is also a big literature overview included, at the end of the book.

May has written much more (just look at his homepage), and I didn't read all of it. But what I read, I liked.

Comment: A true classic with a sequel on the way,as reported here a few months ago. 

Comment: But that's even too difficult for grad course in a semester...

Answer (score 20):

I hope it's not too rude to double-post, but as far as high-quality books go, Fulton's [Algebraic Curves](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf) was also recently made available online.

Comment: Fantastic book! 

Answer (score 15):

And just because I like the book so much, Flajolet and Sedgewick's [Analytic Combinatorics](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/book.pdf) is available online and is a great resource for learning about asymptotic analysis in combinatorics.  The first half is also a great introduction to various techniques for writing down generating functions.

Answer (score 13):

[Abstract and concrete categories: The joy of cats](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/17/tr17abs.html) by Jiri Adamek, Horst Herrlich and George Strecker, is a nice book for learning category theory.  It went out of print, so the authors made it available online for free.

Answer (score 12):

Diestel's [Graph Theory](http://diestel-graph-theory.com/) is probably not as canonical as Hatcher's textbook, but it's a very commonly used textbook for graduate courses in the subject, and it's a similarly broad basic reference.

Answer (score 12):

Not really pointing to a book, but I'd like to let you know I'm soon (within a month or so) launching a site dedicated to this. It is now almost finished. It is going to be a place where people can add mathematical resources, vote on them, add reviews, see other people's favorites and so on. Books will be categorized by language, level, topics, status (draft, lecture notes, books) and so on. I hope I will be able to "advertise" it trough mathoverflow: as with many "social" sites, the more people join, the more interesting it will become.

EDIT: The site is now online. It's still young, but I hope it will improve with time; I certainly have to add some features, but I decided it was time to launch and see if people actually find it useful. You can find it [here](http://mathonline.andreaferretti.it/)

Comment: The link seems to be dead.

Answer (score 12):

http://mathunion.org/ICM/ has almost all volumes of ICM talks online

Comment: Starting from 1893!

Answer (score 10):

I can't believe nobody mentioned :
[NUMDAM](http://www.numdam.org/) and [Göttinger Digitalisierungszentrum](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/), where you'll find digitized versions of mathematical texts... monographies and articles which made mathematical history, but sometimes still count as important references!

Answer (score 8):

Check out Allen Hatcher's [online books](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/#anchor1772800) (topological stuff).

Comment: There's already a different answer about Hatcher's writings.

Answer (score 8):

Volumes 28 through 56 of the MSRI book series are available here:

http://www.msri.org/communications/books/index.html

Answer (score 8):

Paul Garrett is quite the author:

http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/

He has a book on buildings and many vignettes about automorphic forms, L-functions, representation theory, .... He wrote a graduate algebra book while he taught the course, and promptly got it [published](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1584886897).

http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/algebra/

Comment: It's not a bad book,Garrett's-but it's really hard to consider an algebra text in 2010 that doesn't do category theory or homological algebra AT ALL a GRADUATE algebra text.

Comment: @Andrew L: "General Algebra" at the University of Minnesota covers what undergrad algebra would cover, but at a greater depth. I'd say it's sort of like the difference between "calculus" and "advanced calculus".

Also, Garrett makes/grades algebra prelim exams IIRC, so the book is very good preparation. Lastly, I must say he's a very nice guy. He has a very pleasing ideology on mathematics and education (very "I want you to learn" attitude, not "I want you to get a good grade". in fact, in his $L$-functions and automorphic forms class, you get an "A", but you're still required to do work. ;)

Comment: @AndrewL: Garrett's book, like Garrett, is unconventional. As mentioned above, the point is not to do as much algebra as is feasible in a year, the point is to do a good amount of algebra from the "right" (in the Garrett sense, whatever that means) perspective. Most mathematicians do not use category theory or homological algebra at all, and I find a first year graduate text on algebra being devoid of these topics as no great sin. Besides, only a foolish graduate student uses one algebra book.

Answer (score 6):

[Robert Ash](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~r-ash/) is a professor who's in the habit of making his textbooks available online as well.

Answer (score 6):

The two-volume relatively introductory work on operator algebras, *Operator Algebras and Quantum Statistical Mechanics* by O. Bratteli and D. Robinson is available at [Bratteli's website](http://www.math.uio.no/~bratteli/#Books).

Answer (score 6):

[MAA Writing Awards](http://mathdl.maa.org/mathDL/22/)

Answer (score 6):

In [nlab](http://ncatlab.org/nlab) we keep a list of *main* links of archives and free book collections in our main areas of interests (we were intentionally selective there):

For top level directory for math resources see http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/math+resources, from where you can go to [archives](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/math+archives), individual [author collections](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/math+resources+by+indviduals), [blogs](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/math+blogs) and [institutions](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/math+institutions).

Answer (score 5):

A few more recommendations, apparently less well-known:

Saha's "[Principles of Data Analysis](http://www.physik.uzh.ch/~psaha/pda/)" (you seem to have an interest in that field)

Noam Elkies' Lecture Notes (e.g [this one](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~elkies/M259.06/index.html) on Analytic Number Theory) are like small books.

"[Algorithmic Game Theory](http://www.cambridge.org/journals/nisan/downloads/nisan_non-printable.pdf)" by Nisan, Roughgarden, Tardos and Vazirani.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend [Mel Hochster's notes](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~hochster/). The notes for Math 614 and 615 form an introduction to commutative algebra, and 711 is on a different topic (tight closure, Henselization, etc.) every year. I think they're very easy to read.

Answer (score 5):

Stephen Boyd has some good books on his Stanford home page:
http://www.stanford.edu/~boyd/books.html ... especially the one on convex optimization is very good.

Answer (score 4):

IF you want to see free academic video courses from leading universities, just go to

http://www.academicearth.org/

Answer (score 4):

[Information Theory, Inference, and Learning Algorithms](http://www.inference.phy.cam.ac.uk/mackay/itila/) by David MacKay of the Cavendish Laboratory.

Answer (score 4):

And another great source of the lecture notes and stuff is the MIT [OpenCourseWare](http://ocw.mit.edu), in particular the [math section](http://ocw.mit.edu/OcwWeb/Mathematics/index.htm).

Answer (score 4):

A great hidden gem is Shlomo Sternberg's page of online books:

http://www.math.harvard.edu/~shlomo/

Also, Curt McMullen has some notes at the bottom of this page

http://www.math.harvard.edu/~ctm/papers/index.html

which are good, but less formal. He also has other notes on his website not listed there; just look at his list of past courses and follow the links.

Comment: Sternberg's notes are terrific,but pretty well knowm.Curtis McMullen is quietly one of the best teachers among prominent mathematical researchers and his lecture notes are a great addition to the available free online resources.They are fairly sophisticated,though-as would be expected from Harvard coursework-so not for beginners.

Answer (score 4):

The Stacks Project
http://math.columbia.edu/algebraic_geometry/stacks-git/

If I ever wonder about something, I can pretty much count on it to be in there. Remember to use a PDF viewer with hyperlinks and back/next buttons.

Answer (score 4):

I'm glad someone mentioned Keith Conrad's notes, as they are excellent.

I would also like to point people towards [Tom Weston](http://www.math.umass.edu/~weston/)'s webpage. He has expository papers at http://www.math.umass.edu/~weston/ep.html on several topics, including cobordism theory and spectral sequences.

He also has some course notes at http://www.math.umass.edu/~weston/cn.html, including truly excellent book-length notes on introductory algebraic number theory, as well as several dozen illuminating pages on local fields and ideles.

Answer (score 4):

Richard P. Stanley's Enumerative Combinatorics, volume 1, second edition is available
at http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/ec1/ .

Answer (score 3):

'The Elements of Statistical Learning' by Hastie, Tibshirani and Friedman
http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/

Answer (score 3):

Check out Jean-Pierre Demailly's books on analytic algebraic geometry http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~demailly/books.html.

Here you go the AMS book online webpage  http://www.ams.org/online_bks/online_subject.html .

I should also mention the AMS online book webpage collection
http://www.ams.org/online_bks/online-books-web.html.

Answer (score 2):

"[Linear Algebra](http://joshua.smcvt.edu/linearalgebra/)" by Jim Hefferon has been online for a while and it was what I used to teach myself linear algebra. It's very well written with tons of great practice problems and interesting asides. It is a little less advanced than any of the other books listed so far, but it's still a great read. Plus, it's open source (You can download the LaTeX for the book from the website).

Comment: I'm currently teaching linear algebra, and using this book. It's ok and as you say has a lot of good problems. The only drawback is that it's arrangement seems a bit confusing to me, and my students. 

Answer (score 2):

A draft of Albert Marden's *Outer circles: an introduction to hyperbolic 3-manifolds* is online, on his website:

http://www.math.umn.edu/~am/book/outercircles.pdf

Edward Nelson's *Radically elementary probability theory* is also online, on his website:

http://www.math.princeton.edu/~nelson/books/rept.pdf

Answer (score 2):

*Exterior Differential Systems* by Bryant, Chern, Gardner, Goldschmidt, and Griffiths is available through MSRI (and is sadly out of print at the moment).

http://library.msri.org/books/masterlist.html

Comment: Great! Thanks for pointing that out. A pity that the table of contents and index seem to be missing.

Answer (score 1):

[Len Evens](http://www.math.northwestern.edu/~len/) has a couple of online textbooks: a text on abstract algebra, and a linear algebra text.

Comment: Evens, not Evans


Comment: You are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Martin J Osborne and Ariel Rubinstein's book "A course in Game theory" [is available here](http://theory.economics.utoronto.ca/books/index.php/index).

Answer (score 1):

The [Caltechbook](http://caltechbook.library.caltech.edu/) service at Caltech offers a number of math books for free [here](http://caltechbook.library.caltech.edu/view/subjects/optionCDS.html), including some very good (IMHO) books by Jerry Marsden et al.

Answer (score 1):

[Sergei Winitzki](http://sites.google.com/site/winitzki/) has an interesting-looking [book on the coordinate-free approach to linear algebra](http://sites.google.com/site/winitzki/linalg) online.

Answer (score 1):

Jerome Keisler's *Elementary Calculus*.  This book uses infinitesimals explicitly, and also in a logically rigorous way, without getting too advanced for first-year undergraduates.

**Later edit:** http://math.wisc.edu/~keisler/calc.html

Comment: A url would be nice.

Comment: http://www.math.wisc.edu/~keisler/calc.html

Answer (score 1):

Gerald Teschl books

1. Textbook Ordinary Differential Equations and Dynamical Systems
2. Textbook Mathematical Methods in Quantum Mechanics; With Applications to Schrödinger Operators

can be found at http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~gerald/

Answer (score 1):

Within the framework of the project [retro.seals.ch](http://retro.seals.ch/digbib/home), scientific journals are retrodigitized and made available via internet. The project contains the following mathematical journals:

- [Commentarii Mathematici Helvetici](http://retro.seals.ch/digbib/vollist?UID=comahe-001,comahe-002,comahe-003&id=home&id2=browse4)
- Elemente der Mathematik
- Elemente der Mathematik (Beihefte zur Zeitschrift)
- L'Enseignement Mathématique

Answer (score 0):

http://www.cs.utk.edu/~dongarra/etemplates/book.html

Answer (score 0):

As with so many things, "There's a reddit for that":  http://www.reddit.com/r/mathbooks.  It's a mixed bag—much like searching for math books in a non-specialist bookstore, one gets the elementary mixed up with the sophisticated—but there are some gems there.

Answer (score 0):

Roland Speicher has some nice introductory material for Free Probability (mini course, survey articles etc.) All available at http://www.mast.queensu.ca/~speicher/survey.html

Comment: This link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Jim Pitman's *Combinatorial Stochastic Processes*.

**Later edit:** http://works.bepress.com/jim_pitman/1

Comment: A url would be nice.

Comment: http://works.bepress.com/jim_pitman/1/

Answer (score 0):

*Basic Concepts of Enriched Category Theory* by G.M. Kelly was originally published by Cambridge University Press in 1982 but is now available online:
http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/10/tr10abs.html

My understanding is that it is the canonical reference for enriched category theory (and was written by the pioneer of the field).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.oocities.com/alex_stef/mylist.html

Answer (score 0):

Book by David Levin, Yuval Peres and Elizabeth Wilmor on Markov chain theory and mixing times. http://pages.uoregon.edu/dlevin/MARKOV/markovmixing.pdf. It quickly takes someone with basic knowledge in probability and linear algebra into the heart of current research.

Answer (score 0):

The website of the Leibniz award offers a free online collection: [*link*](http://www.leibniz-publik.de/en/fs1/about/static.html), and there is the [*preprint server of the IHES*](http://preprints.ihes.fr/index.php).

Answer (score 0):

The [Comptes Rendus de l'Académie des Sciences](http://www.academie-sciences.fr/activite/cr.htm) are available online.