# papers archives? (especially not indexed by google) 

Tags: big-list

http://www.digizeitschriften.de/index.php?id=239&L=2
has many papers with free access (e.g. Inventiones Mathematicae)
but when you search with scholar.google.com it does not index this site!

Are there any other archives like this?

Just in case let me list other archives (they are indexed by google as far as I understand).

http://projecteuclid.org

http://www.numdam.org/?lang=fr

http://www.math.uiuc.edu/K-theory/

PS

e.g. I cannot find:

Koszul, J (1981), "Les algebres de Lie graduées de type sl (n, 1) et l'opérateur de A. Capelli", C.R. Acad. Sci. Paris (292): 139-141

Does it mean search skills are poor or it is really not available electronically?

Comment: Reagarding your specific question it seems from here http://www.academie-sciences.fr/activite/cr.htm that they are available until 1965 and then recent ones. So your 1981 might actually fall into the gap; not sure though. In particular following the link leads to Gallica, the electronic branch of the BNF the French national librey,  http://gallica.bnf.fr/ 
You might also be interested in some answers to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/1722/ on free math online , which IMO is close to a duplicated but then is closed and is not exactly the same. 

 

Comment: @Quid thank you for the comment. I am still unlucky - cannot find it there. http://www.em-consulte.com/revue/crass1 - shows that they have volumes only from 2001... 

Comment: I tried to search a bit in Gallica but no luck either. It seems there is now already more available than said on the acad. sci. site but still this one is not (yet?) there it seems. On cean find 1984 -- 1996 or so. And pre 80s or so. But almost just the one you arelooking for +/-1 are not there. Sorry.

Answer (score 19):

The AMS maintains a page listing all journals available electronically:

http://www.ams.org/dmr/

From time to time I have requested them to add a journal which wasn't already there on their list; if more people do so regularly, this might become the first place to visit when looking for an old article.

Answer (score 13):

Within the framework of the project [retro.seals.ch](http://retro.seals.ch/digbib/home), scientific journals are retrodigitized and made available via internet. The project contains the following mathematical journals:

- [Commentarii Mathematici Helvetici](http://retro.seals.ch/digbib/vollist?UID=comahe-001,comahe-002,comahe-003&id=home&id2=browse4)
- [Elemente der Mathematik](http://retro.seals.ch/digbib/vollist?UID=comahe-001,comahe-002,comahe-003&id=home&id2=browse4)
- [Elemente der Mathematik (Beihefte zur Zeitschrift)](http://retro.seals.ch/digbib/vollist?UID=comahe-001,comahe-002,comahe-003&id=home&id2=browse4)
- [L'Enseignement Mathématique](http://retro.seals.ch/digbib/vollist?UID=comahe-001,comahe-002,comahe-003&id=home&id2=browse4)

Comment: and also Helvetic Physica Acta which has some important papers in mathematical physics.

Answer (score 11):

Many Russian journals (at least up to 2008) are available free of charge via the portal http://www.mathnet.ru/ej.phtml?&option_lang=eng

Answer (score 4):

Ulf Rehmann from Bielefeld has a comprehensive list of electronically available journals (with 318 items)

http://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/~rehmann/DML/dml_links.html

As Chandan says, this list could perhaps be added to AMS.

Comment: @Shripad: Nice to see you here.  The AMS digital registry says that [The registry was inspired by work of the Committee on Electronic Information and Communication of the International Mathematical Union, as well as by Ulf Rehmann's Digital Mathematics Library.]

Answer (score 3):

The [EuDML](http://eudml.org/) is an interesting project that makes mathematics published in Europe available online.

Answer (score 2):

[This site](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/) from the university of Goettingen is a goldmine, especially for [old issues of Journal für die reine und angewandte Mathematik ("Crelle")](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/toc/?PPN=PPN243919689)

Comment: as well as Math. Annalen and many other journals.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness I will add Axriv.

http://arxiv.org/

Answer (score 1):

Here is another German list of online journals, with indication of those freely available:

http://rzblx1.uni-regensburg.de/ezeit/fl.phtml?bibid=UBK&colors=7&lang=de&notation=SA-SP

I find it very convenient.
I did not compare it carefully with the AMS list.

Answer (score 1):

For the dutch literature we may search in Narcis

http://www.narcis.nl/?Language=en

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at the "Digitization Registry" (http://DigReg.MathGuide.de/) in Göttingen.